# Writing DataFrames as partitioned parquet object in Polars with PyArrow

Tags: python, memory, parquet, python-polars, pyarrow

I have 12 parquet files in a directory with matching columns I am trying to write to a partitioned object with Polars and PyArrow. I am iterating through each file in the directory and reading it in as a LazyFrame. I am then iterating through the list of DataFrames and writing them to the partitioned object. The estimated size of each DataFrame is ~1GB, and all the DataFrames concatenated ~10GB. The process uses ~15GB RAM and completes in under an hour.

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
all_lazyframes: list[pl.LazyFrame] = []

for file in glob.glob(input_path):
    lazyframe: pl.LazyFrame = pl.scan_parquet(file)
    all_lazyframes.append(lazyframe)

dataframes: list[pl.DataFrame] = pl.collect_all(all_lazyframes)

for output in dataframes:
    output.write_parquet(
        output_path,
        use_pyarrow=True,
        pyarrow_options={"partition_cols": ["part"]},
    )
```

The resulting partitioned object has the following structure:

```
partitioned_object/
  part=a/
       data0.parquet
       data1.parquet
       ...
  part=b/
       data0.parquet
       data1.parquet
    ...
```

This object is ~250GB in size. My question is, why is the partitioned object so large when the input data is only ~10GB total? Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: I'm assuming there are a ton of new files, is that right?

Comment: There are 13 parquet files in each partition, so 26 in total

Comment: So you're going from 12 files taking up 10GB in total to 26 files taking 250GBs in total? My initial guess was going to be that you had so many files that the efficiency of compression was getting lost and the accumulation of metadata was getting you. Since you're only getting a little over double the files, I wouldn't think that would explain 25x the size, unless I'm missing something. You can compare the files with this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_metadata.html

Comment: Input parquet file metadata: <pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData object at 0x108892200>
  created_by: parquet-cpp-arrow version 10.0.1
  num_columns: 14
  num_rows: 10000000
  num_row_groups: 1
  format_version: 2.6
  serialized_size: 3515
Parquet file in partitioned object: <pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData object at 0x108892200>
  created_by: parquet-cpp-arrow version 13.0.0
  num_columns: 13
  num_rows: 5000000
  num_row_groups: 306
  format_version: 2.6
  serialized_size: 297097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by specifying the size of rows per group in the ds.write_dataset() function. The polars method currently takes longer and you cannot specify number of rows per group while using the PyArrow option.

```
ds.write_dataset(
        data,
        output_path,
        format="parquet",
        min_rows_per_group=1000000,
        max_rows_per_group=1000000,
        partitioning=ds.partitioning(pa.schema([("type", pa.string())])),
        existing_data_behavior="overwrite_or_ignore"
    )
```

Polars method takes longer and row_group_size option does not work when using PyArrow options:

```
    output.write_parquet(
       file=output_path,
       use_pyarrow=True,
       pyarrow_options={"partition_cols": partition_cols},
       row_group_size=1000000,
    )
```

Comment: It works if you pass it through pyarrow_options dict